# $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12},i)$ is a simple extension of $\Bbb Q $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is proving $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12},i) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} +i)$ the same as proving that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12},i)$ is a simple extension of $\Bbb Q$, if not could anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Let $\alpha =\sqrt{12}+i$ and note that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 9 & 35\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{12}\\ i\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \alpha ^3\end{bmatrix}_.$ The left-most matrix is invertible which proves that both $\sqrt{12}$ and $i$ are in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

Comment: It's not quite the same. Showing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12} + i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12},i)$ of course shows that the latter is a simple extension. But showing that it is a simple extension doesn't (necessarily) include showing that $\sqrt{12}+i$ is a primitive element of that extension. It is possible that $K(\alpha,\beta) = K(\alpha + 2\beta) \supsetneqq K(\alpha + \beta)$.

Comment: So this means that i have just proven it for a specific example and not in general?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have shown that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12}, i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12} + i)$, according to a comment under an answer. Thus you have shown that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12},i)$ is a simple extension, and something else, namely that $\sqrt{12}+i$ is a primitive element of that extension. But you could have shown that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12},i)$ is simple without showing that $\sqrt{12}+i$ is a primitive element, for example by showing that $\sqrt{12} + 5i$ is a primitive element.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i)$. If you next can show that $\sqrt{12}$ and $i$ are both contained in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)$, you're done. This might be a bit of work, but see what you can do with $\sqrt{12} + i, (\sqrt{12} + i)^2$ and $(\sqrt{12} + i)^3$.

Optionally, you can do it using extension degrees. Because $4 = [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q] = [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)]\cdot [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q]$, showing that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q] >2$ means that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)] = 1$, which is to say they are the same.

Comment: i have shown that $\Bbb Q \sqrt 12 ,i$=$\Bbb Q \sqrt 12 + i$ , does that mean i have proven that the lhs is a simple extension of just $\Bbb Q $ or would i need to do it for the other cases? Thanks for the optional method though  it's is always great to learn different methods of solving a problem.

Comment: And also for the using the extension degrees would you need to calculate the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt 12 + i $

Comment: @Alwayslearning What's the definition of simple extension of a field $F$?

Comment: @GitGud  a simple extension of a Field $ F$  we say f is a simple extension of F if $\alpha $ is in f such that $f$=$F(\alpha)$ Where F(alpha) is the smallest sub field of f containing both F and alpha?

Comment: @Alwayslearning If you've shown that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)$, then you've shown that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i)$ is a simple extension over $\Bbb Q$. And no, in this case, for extension degrees you don't need to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{12} + i$. The reason is that the degree $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q$ is $4$, which means that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)]\cdot [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q] = 4$.

Comment: (cont.) This is the product of two natural numbers, so the moment you've shown that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q] >2$ (i.e. that the minimal polynomial cannot be first or second degree), then you know that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q] = 4$. So you need to do some reasoning about the minimal polynomial, but you don't have to come anywhere close to actually finding it.

Comment: you mentioned they are the product of two natural numbers would these then be 2 and 2? i dont understand why the degree of $\Bbb [Q(\sqrt12,i)]:[\Bbb Q(\sqrt12 +i)]=1 can you explain this please?

Comment: @Alwayslearning Exactly. Can you now tell what $\alpha, F$ and $f$ are in your question, thus completing the problem?

Comment: @Alwayslearning Regarding your question to Arthur, did you mean to ask about $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)]\cdot [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q] = 4$ instead of $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}, i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i)]\cdot [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12} + i):\Bbb Q] = 1$?

Comment: @GitGud yes i thought it would be the because if the degree of the first one is 1 why do we just skip the case that the degree of the second part is not three?

Comment: @GitGud would alpha be sqrt 12,i and f= sqrt 12 +i , and F is Q?

Comment: @Alwayslearning It can't be $3$, because you have two integers that multiply to become $4$. Also, $\alpha$ should be a single number, not two. And $f$ should be a field, not a number.

Comment: So the degree of both of them must be greater than two? So why is it equal to four and not greater than?

Comment: No. Showing that the degree $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}+i):\Bbb Q]$ is greater than $2$ means that it must be $4$ and that the other degree, $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12},i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}+i)]$ must be $1$ (again, since their product must be $4$), which again means that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12},i)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}+i)$.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is show that the degree of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}+i)$ has degree $4$ since clearly $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{12}+i)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt{12},i)$ and the latter has degree $4$.

Now note that since all degree $2$ extensions of $\Bbb Q$ are of the form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ for some square-free integer $d$ we write

> $$\sqrt{12}+i = 2\sqrt 3 + i = a+b\sqrt d$$

clearly $d<0$ or else there is no imaginary part, but then $bi\sqrt{|d|}=i$ implying $b= {1\over\sqrt{|d|}}$ which is impossible as $b$ is rational and $\sqrt{|d|}$ is not. So $\sqrt{12}+i$ is not contained in any quadratic extension, so it must be that it generates an extension of degree $4$, i.e. the whole field.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(\sqrt{12}+i)^2=11-2i\sqrt{12}$, so $i\sqrt{12}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12}+i)$.

Therefore $(\sqrt{12}+i)i\sqrt{12}=12i-\sqrt{12}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12}+i)$.

Can you prove from this that $i\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{12}+i)$?

Comment: yes you can by using by using the third subfield axiom  and by using the second one also, as you can write $\sqrt12+i+(-\sqrt12)$ element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt12 + i)$

Comment: well i think this is a way to show it but if it isnt could you correct me?

Comment: @Alwayslearning $(\sqrt{12}+i)+(12i-\sqrt{12})=13i$; dividing by $13$ is allowed.

Comment: i think i have done it in a different way.  can you confirm if it is correct $\frac{1}{\sqrt12 +i}$ belongs to $\Bbb Q(\sqrt12 +i)$ now by sf4 we get  $(\sqrt12 +i)(\sqrt12+i) = 12-1=11$ thus $\sqrt12 -i=11(\frac{1}{\sqrt12+i})$ but 11 and (1/sqrt12 +i) are both in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt12 -i)$ now by sft $sqrt(12+i)+(\sqrt12 -i) which is an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt12+i)$ hence $2 \sqrt12$ belongs in Q(sqrt12+i) so by sf4 root 12 is in there also then just applying sf3 and sf2 we get that -root12 is also in there thus $\sqrt12 +i +(-\sqrt12)=i$ which therefore must be in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt12+i)$

Comment: @Alwayslearning That's another way for seeing it